# How to use Loopback's relations like hasAndBelongsToMany in AOR (Admin on REST)

Tags: reactjs, loopbackjs, admin-on-rest

I really do like the easy way of using and integrating the "Admin on REST" (AOR) with Loopback, but I can't find out to get the relations in Loopback working.

**Question**

How can I use the Loopback API in AOR, when I use the *relations* types like **hasAndBelongsToMany** and **HasMany**?

I need to do Read, Update and Delete on an existing book to an existing author. But also as a datagrid view, where I can see which book relates to which author.

**Example**

I have a book which contains multiple authors and also authors who have written multiple books, which will be build as a GET /book/{id}/authors.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how Loopback API is specific to you question - especially the part with *relations types*, but from the official react-admin [documentation](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Fields.html#referencefield) you can see how relations can be represented within a Datagrid. 
Moreover, keep in mind that react-admin only deals with API calls, converting REST requests to HTTP requests and HTTP responses to REST. 
This is done through the dataProvider, where you can write you custom functions. 
The basic concept for the communication of you admin panel to your Loopback back-end though, are the requests, so I don't think that *relation types* have anything to do with react-admin.

Comment: Hi @Panos, thanks for a very good and precise answer. 

Could you help me out on a tutorial or article, where they build a custom functions for the dataProvider in react-admin? I'm missing the part where I POST or PUT data in a structure that's not standard REST in react-admin.

Like e.g. a book needs to be connected to an author, I'm using the following API call:
/api/book/5aba453464bb4c45bd2a3d5c/authors/rel/5aba43e564bb4c45bd2a3d5a

This will connect the book and author together in the backend, and works fine in the API, but I can't find a way to do it in react-admin.

Comment: @Niller2000 well, if you want to use react-admin, the API provided by your back-end, should either be REST or GraphQL API, as react-admin is made for/supports these two. 
Now for the custom dataProvider, you can see here: (https://marmelab.com/react-admin/DataProviders.html#example-implementation).
As for the relation between you objects, this is done strictly through your back-end. 
Perhaps you should consider filters? 
LoopBack is not my expertise so I cannot help you with that. 
If what I proposed sounds unreasonable, maybe react-admin is not what you need.